# postgres psql error trying to pass parameters in sql script

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In postgresql, I'm `psql` with the `-v` for variable input that I can call within a sql file.

For example from bash script, it looks like this:

```
"$PSQL_HOME"/psql -h $HOST_NM     \
                      -p $PORT    \
                      -U postgres \
                      -v v1=$1    \
                      -f Test.sql
...
..
```

From the sql file, it looks like this:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE mytable TO mra_dev_:v1;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE mytable TO mra_dev_:v1_load;
```

The first statement works, but the 2nd statement fails:

```
psql:Test.sql:472: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 1: GRANT ALL ON TABLE mytable TO mra_dev_:v1_load
                                              ^
```

How do I get around this? Somekind of escape or concat feature I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround was to add the string I needed to the parameter when called on the command line like this:

```
"$PSQL_HOME"/psql -h $HOST_NM     \
                      -p $PORT    \
                      -U postgres \
                      -v v1=$1    \
                      -v v2=$_load \
                      -f Test.sql
```

Then within the sql file, changed this:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE mytable TO mra_dev_:v2;
```

It works now.